# Add item to ArrayList

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, arraylist

I'm having issues populating an ArrayList.
As the loop goes on the first item in ArrayList is replaced with the second/third/fourth/.. item until it reaches the end of range. And instead of having 10 items I end up with 5.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
Set Rng = Range("B7:C1000")
Set dateNtimes = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For Each c In Rng
    If Len(c) > 0 Then
        If c.Row Mod 2 = 1 Then
            datev = c
        ElseIf c.Row Mod 2 = 0 Then
            timev = c
        End If
        If Len(datev) > 0 And Len(timev) > 0 Then
            dateNtime = datev & timev
            dateNtimes.Add dateNtime
            datev = ""
            timev = ""
        End If
    End If
Next c
```

LE: Fixed it by removing `datev = ""`. Can someone explain what was happening before?

Comment: If you have 10 populated cells,  you should only end up with 5 items, since the code combines each pair of cells into a date and time combination.

Comment: I have 20 populated cells. Fixed it by removing `datev = ""`. Still don't understand the mentioned result.

Comment: Could have a shot at explaining it, but we need really to know what is in the first few cells of the range  B7:C1000. Presumably alternating dates and times, but in what order? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @Tom Sharpe Here:
[screenshot](https://pasteimg.com/images/2021/09/17/Untitled.png)